# Graticules for WMS maps

Tags: geoserver, wms, grids-graticules

How to utilise Graticules for WMS maps in GeoServer 2.25 rc? I am unable to locate the plugin in community section to install in my GeoServer 2.25rc. I have also searched for it in geoserver -2.25 nighty. Beside this after installing the pluggin in my local GeoServer 2.25 how to proceed with it, like data to utilised and further processing? Can it be used as a WMS layer in OpenLayers?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question to focus on one question,.

Answer (score 1):

It appears not to have been added to the community release job, but you can fetch the source code from github and build it directly.

I'll see if I can [work out how to release it](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-11216), though I thought it was done.

### update

I think the issue is now fixed and should show up in tomorrow's nightly build.

### 2nd Update

The plugin is now [available for *main*](https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/main/community-latest/geoserver-2.26-SNAPSHOT-graticule-plugin.zip) and now that works will be available in 2.25.x from tomorrow (16th March).

Comment: Thank you for prompt response.

Comment: I have one more doubt regarding the usage of extension especially related to the parameter 'Sizes of Graticules, comma separated list *' , how can one confiugured these parameter while generating the graticule store for different crs.